# Why am I not getting all values exported to my csv file?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am only getting 308 rows on my CSV file. Where I should get more than 900 rows. I have written this below code. I am tried to change the iteration in links. But still the same. getting the amount of data every time. Is it problem with my data frame declaration or anything else?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as ps

#list of dataframe

suppliers_name = []
suppliers_location = []
suppliers_type = []
suppliers_content = []
suppliers_est =[]
suppliers_income = []

def parse(url):
    web = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web.content, "html.parser")

    container = soup.find_all(class_ = "supplier-search-results__card profile-card profile-card profile-card--secondary supplier-tier-1")

    for cont in container:
        # getting the names

        name = cont.find("h2").text
        suppliers_name.append(name)

        #getting the locations

        location =cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data").find("a").text[8:]
        if "  " in location:
            suppliers_location.append(location.replace("  ",""))
        elif "Locations" in location:
            suppliers_location.append(location.replace("Locations", "None"))

        #suppliers type
        
        types = cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data").find_all("span")[1].text[2:]
        suppliers_type.append(types.replace("*", ""))

        # suppliers content

        content = cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__body-text").find("p").text
        suppliers_content.append(content)

        # suppliers establishment

        years = cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data").find_all("span", {"data-toggle":"popover"})
        if len(years) == 4:
            year = cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data").find_all("span", {"data-toggle":"popover"})[2].text
            suppliers_est.append(year[5:])
            
        elif len(years) == 3:
            year = cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data").find_all("span", {"data-toggle":"popover"})[1].text
            word =year[5:]
            if len(word) != 4:
                suppliers_est.append("None")
            else:
                suppliers_est.append(word) 
        
        elif len(years) == 2:
            year = cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data").find_all("span", {"data-toggle":"popover"})[1].text
            suppliers_est.append(year[5:])
        
        elif len(years)==1:
            suppliers_est.append("None")

        # suppliers income

        incomes =  cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data").find_all("span", {"data-toggle":"popover"})
        if len(incomes) == 4:
            income = cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data").find_all("span", {"data-toggle":"popover"})[1].text
            suppliers_income.append(income[4:])
        
        elif len(incomes) == 3:
            income = cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data").find_all("span", {"data-toggle":"popover"})[1].text
            word = income[4:]
            if len(word) != 5:
                suppliers_income.append(word)
            else:
                suppliers_income.append("None")
        elif len(incomes) == 2:
            suppliers_income.append("None")
        
        elif len(incomes) == 1:
            suppliers_income.append("None")

#iterate over links
number = 1
num =1
for i in range(43):
    urls = f'https://www.thomasnet.com/nsearch.html?_ga=2.53813992.1582589371.1586649402-45317423.1586649402&cov=NA&heading=97010359&pg={num}'
    parse(urls)
    num += 1
    print("\n" f'{number} - done')
    number += 1

#dataframe

covid = ps.DataFrame({
    "Name of the Suppliers": suppliers_name,
    "Location": suppliers_location,
    "Type of the suppliers": suppliers_type,
    "Establishment of the supplies": suppliers_est,
    "Motive": suppliers_content
})

covid.to_csv("E:/New folder/covid.csv", index=False)
print("File Creation Done")
```

code works without any error but I am not getting all data.

Comment: the class attribute you are looking for is not consistent in all the pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class attributes change after a few pages: ie goes from `"supplier-search-results__card profile-card profile-card profile-card--secondary supplier-tier-1"` to `"supplier-search-results__card profile-card profile-card profile-card--tertiary "` (and thats just 1 that I noticed, it appears to be more).

So as an alternative, it looks to me like they all have an id attribute that starts with `pc`. You can try that (find all elements that have id attribute that starts with `pc`.)

There also errors in your logic if statements in that you don't catch all the scenarios. For example, at some point, location is " ", but you only check for double white space in front of the city, state. And it also doesn't have `"Locations"` in it, so it gets passed up and you end up with a different length of locations in your list. Best to just use `.strip()` the whitespace, and then don't even need to use an if there and/or use replace as that will take care of the whitespace in the string.

Finally, not a huge deal, but I've seen majority of pandas users import as `pd` and opposed to `ps`

So I think this code gets what you want, and in fact, it gives me 1065 rows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as ps

#list of dataframe

suppliers_name = []
suppliers_location = []
suppliers_type = []
suppliers_content = []
suppliers_est =[]
suppliers_income = []

def parse(urls):
    web = requests.get(urls, headers={})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web.content, "html.parser")

    
    container = soup.find_all(id=re.compile("^pc"))  # <----- Fixed this line' find all id attributes that start with pc
    for cont in container:
        # getting the names

        name = cont.find("h2").text
        suppliers_name.append(name)

        #getting the locations

        location =cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data").find("a").text[8:]
        if "Locations" in location:
            suppliers_location.append(location.replace("Locations", "None"))
        else:
            suppliers_location.append(location.strip()) # <----- Fixed this line

        #suppliers type

        types = cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data").find_all("span")[1].text[2:]
        suppliers_type.append(types.replace("*", ""))

        # suppliers content

        content = cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__body-text").find("p").text
        suppliers_content.append(content)

        # suppliers establishment

        years = cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data").find_all("span", {"data-toggle":"popover"})
        if len(years) == 4:
            year = cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data").find_all("span", {"data-toggle":"popover"})[2].text
            suppliers_est.append(year[5:])

        elif len(years) == 3:
            year = cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data").find_all("span", {"data-toggle":"popover"})[1].text
            word =year[5:]
            if len(word) != 4:
                suppliers_est.append("None")
            else:
                suppliers_est.append(word) 

        elif len(years) == 2:
            year = cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data").find_all("span", {"data-toggle":"popover"})[1].text
            suppliers_est.append(year[5:])

        elif len(years)==1:
            suppliers_est.append("None")

        # suppliers income

        incomes =  cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data").find_all("span", {"data-toggle":"popover"})
        if len(incomes) == 4:
            income = cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data").find_all("span", {"data-toggle":"popover"})[1].text
            suppliers_income.append(income[4:])

        elif len(incomes) == 3:
            income = cont.find(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data").find_all("span", {"data-toggle":"popover"})[1].text
            word = income[4:]
            if len(word) != 5:
                suppliers_income.append(word)
            else:
                suppliers_income.append("None")
        elif len(incomes) == 2:
            suppliers_income.append("None")

        elif len(incomes) == 1:
            suppliers_income.append("None")

#iterate over links
number = 1
num =1
for i in range(43):
    urls = f'https://www.thomasnet.com/nsearch.html?_ga=2.53813992.1582589371.1586649402-45317423.1586649402&cov=NA&heading=97010359&pg={num}'
    parse(urls)
    num += 1
    print("\n" f'{number} - done')
    number += 1

#dataframe

covid = ps.DataFrame({
    "Name of the Suppliers": suppliers_name,
    "Location": suppliers_location,
    "Type of the suppliers": suppliers_type,
    "Establishment of the supplies": suppliers_est,
    "Motive": suppliers_content
})
```

**Output:**

```
print (covid)
                                  Name of the Suppliers  ...                                             Motive
0                                 All Metal Sales, Inc.  ...  Supplier providing services and products for C...
1                                   Ellsworth Adhesives  ...  We are a large distributor with the ability to...
2                           Monroe Engineering Products  ...  Proud member of the Defense Industrial Base an...
3                       New Process Fibre Company, Inc.  ...  We supply parts to help produce the following ...
4                               Vanguard Products Corp.  ...  Custom manufacturing available for component p...
5                                      Techmetals, Inc.  ...  We are a certified metal plating facility, hol...
6                                       The Rodon Group  ...  We can design, mold and manufacturer plastic i...
7                                           Mardek, LLC  ...  Mardek LLC's core business is sourcing manufac...
8                         Allstates Rubber & Tool Corp.  ...  Materials or component parts are available tha...
9                    Estes Design & Manufacturing, Inc.  ...  We are a sheet metal fabricator still in opera...
10                         Nadco Tapes and Labels, Inc.  ...  We are manufacturer of tapes and labels capabl...
11                              NewAge Industries, Inc.  ...  We are a manufacturer and fabricator of plasti...
12                                       Associated Bag  ...  We are a nationwide supplier of packaging, shi...
13                                              3D Hubs  ...  Surgical masks - we have started a GoFundMe ra...
14                        Tailored Label Products, Inc.  ...  In response to the COVID-19 crisis, we're prov...
15                         Compressed Air Systems, Inc.  ...  We are specialists in compressed air, we can d...
16                               A & S Mold & Die Corp.  ...  Custom manufacturing available for component p...
17                                 Vibromatic Co., Inc.  ...  We manufacture custom part handling systems. I...
18                           Wyandotte Industries, Inc.  ...  Wyandotte Industries is a manufacturer of Spec...
19                                            MOCAP LLC  ...  We manufacture a full line of protective caps,...
20                       Emco Industrial Plastics, Inc.  ...  Custom manufacturer of guards, divider and fac...
21                   Bracalente Manufacturing Co., Inc.  ...  We specialize in complex and high volume turne...
22                             Liberty Industries, Inc.  ...  Engineers, designs and builds cleanrooms, modu...
23                                 Waples Manufacturing  ...  We are using our expertise in CNC precision ma...
24                                   Griff Paper & Film  ...  In response to the COVID-19 crisis, we are cur...
25                              The Hollaender Mfg. Co.  ...  Hollaender is a manufacturer supplying key inf...
26                                    IFM Efector, Inc.  ...  We offer durably tested and highly reliable se...
27                           Precision Associates, Inc.  ...  We are ramping up our production of several es...
28                                            LBU, Inc.  ...  For the production of in demand COVID response...
29                              EMC Precision Machining  ...  Available to custom manufacture component part...
                                                ...  ...                                                ...
1035                   Chembio Diagnostic Systems, Inc.  ...  Manufacturer of rapid PCR test kits for aid in...
1036                                        Innuscience  ...  Manufacturer of biotechnology based, environme...
1037                                Baumgartner Machine  ...  In response to the COVID-19 crisis, we can off...
1038                            Resitech Industries LLC  ...  We can provide face masks and face shields for...
1039                                   Bean, L.L., Inc.  ...  We can supply face masks to assist during the ...
1040                       Trinity Medical Devices Inc.  ...  Supplies and materials for respirators - Certa...
1041                                        Prent Corp.  ...  We can supply face shields that can be used du...
1042                                          GDC, Inc.  ...  Extensive range of machinery available to supp...
1043                      Honeywell International, Inc.  ...  We can supply face masks that can be used duri...
1044                                    Scan Group, The  ...  We are adapting part of our production to manu...
1045                    Advanced Sterilization Products  ...  We can supply face masks that can be used duri...
1046        International Wire Dies div. of DS Hai, LLC  ...  We have access to 3D printers so we can make s...
1047                         Prima Strategic Group Inc.  ...  We are a Houston, TX based organization and wi...
1048                               R+L Global Logistics  ...  We can ship anything, anytime, anywhere. We ar...
1049                          Interiors by Maite Granda  ...  If you need materials or component parts, we h...
1050                                        Pioneer IWS  ...  Prototyping services and mass production offer...
1051                                American Belleville  ...  Custom component part manufacturing available ...
1052                                     PSP Seals, LLC  ...  We have access to supplies of Chinese made KN9...
1053                    Gulf States International, Inc.  ...  We manufacture hand sanitizer for COVID-19 res...
1054                   Prochem Specialty Products, Inc.  ...  We manufacturer biodegradable and environmenta...
1055  Business & Industry Resource Solutions LLC, (B...  ...  During the COVID-19 crisis, we are supplying M...
1056                           Boardman Molded Products  ...  Custom thermoplastic injection molding company...
1057                          Machine Safety Management  ...  We are a manufacturing company with engineers ...
1058                                           JN White  ...  Manufacturing a proprietary all-in-one-piece f...
1059                                        New Balance  ...  We can supply face masks that can be used duri...
1060                                       Rhino Health  ...  One stop nitrile exam glove manufacturer. We h...
1061                               Orchid International  ...  Able to custom manufacture rapid PCR test kits...
1062                            MegaPlast United States  ...  We manufacture mobile hospital shelters, corps...
1063                                       Lion Apparel  ...  We can supply protective clothing that can be ...
1064                                   NuMa Group, Inc.  ...  Manufacturer of supplies and materials capable...

[1065 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: check my answer :P

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd

params = {
    "_ga": "2.53813992.1582589371.1586649402-45317423.1586649402",
    "cov": "NA",
    "heading": "97010359",
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        goal = []
        for item in range(1, 44):
            print(f"Extracting Page # {item}")

            params['pg'] = item
            r = req.get(url, params=params)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            target = soup.findAll("div", id=re.compile("^pc"))

            for tar in target:
                names = tar.select_one("h2.profile-card__title").text
                location = tar.find(
                    "span", {"data-template": True}).previous_element.strip()
                try:
                    types = tar.select("path")[5].next_element.strip()
                except:
                    types = tar.select("path")[2].next_element.strip()
                years = "".join([yr.group(1)
                                 for yr in re.finditer(r"g> (\d{4})<", str(tar))])
                descs = tar.select_one(
                    "div.profile-card__body-text").next_element.text
                data = [names, location, types, years, descs]
                goal.append(data)

        df = pd.DataFrame(
            goal, columns=['Name', 'Location', 'Type', 'Year', 'Description'])
        print(df)
        df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)


main("https://www.thomasnet.com/nsearch.html")
```

Output: [View-Online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/9db17f59ee2f9fe464cd1b766405046c/data.csv)

```
[1065 rows x 5 columns]
```

Each page include `25` items but the last page include only `15` items.

So `25` * `42` = `1050` + `15` = `1065` (`Total of 43 Pages`).

[image]